# Storage size in chainsaw v2

Tags: java, log4j, monitoring, apache-chainsaw

I have a java application now i want to infrastructure monitor for my application logs at run time. I am using log4j for logging.I have filtering(monitoring) logs with chainsaw v2.Its working fine but my concern is how much logs data showing in chainsaw log console.[image] please give me any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer storage of chainsaw buffer size is 5000(means 5MB) goto view->show application-wide preperences -> general -> cyclic buffer size. you can see the image below[image]